# forEach function scoping - how to parse array to function without repeat function calls

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a function that I call and within the function I use a promise, I also want to call this function ( it's actually the second function called in the code) first, retrieve some data, then parse this data through after my second function which calls out to also retrieve some data.

```
      getAllProductGroups(): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.allEngagementTypes().subscribe(data => {
        const products = {};
        const potentialEvents = [];
        data.forEach(product => {
          // products[product.id] = product.description;
          this.potentialForEvents(this.organization.id, product.id)
          .subscribe(potentialEventData => {

            potentialEvents.push(potentialEventData);

            this.allEngagementAreas().subscribe(areas => {

              this.organization.addAreas(areas, potentialEvents);
              resolve();
            }, error => reject(error));
          });
        });   
      })
    });
  }
```

I call the forEach on the first function call **allEngagementTypes**, as I need to use each element to then make my second function call on **potentialForEvents**, then I create an array with the responses with **potentialEvents.push**,

I want to then with this array, parse it after my third call '**allEngagementAreas**' as when this calls on the 'addAreas' function, I want to parse the array **potentialEvents**, but because of the forEach It is sent 21 times, only two of which area actually sent before the 'addAreas' fully loads, I need just one array to be sent and for it to be parsed and be ready before the **allEngagementAreas** is actually called.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You say 'an error wasn't being handled' but now it is. Can you add the code for this please?

Comment: Log the `this` before calling the function and see what context it belongs to.

Comment: Could you post the code completely. Including the content in methods. Please format the code before updating. Its very difficult to read the above code.

Comment: Okay, sure, will do!

Answer (score 0):

if I understood your problem correctly:

```
getAllProductGroups(): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.allEngagementTypes().subscribe(data => {
        const products = {};
        const potentialEvents = [];
        data.forEach(product => {
          // products[product.id] = product.description;
          this.potentialForEvents(this.organization.id, product.id)
          .subscribe(potentialEventData => {
            potentialEvents.push(potentialEventData);
            if(potentialEvents.length === someConstValue) { //not sure how, but you need to find out the needed array length
                resolve(potentialEvents);
            }
          });
        });   
      })
    }).then(potentialEvents => {
        this.allEngagementAreas().subscribe(areas => {
            this.organization.addAreas(areas, potentialEvents);
        }, error => reject(error));
    })

  }
```

main idea is to split it to two promises, and resolve the first one when the array if filled. in forEach loops they usually compare the result length with some const value.

Comment: Okay so I think that's what I was missing in my knowledge! So whatever you 'resolve' in resolve(something) is then used by .then('something'

Comment: in your example I get the error 'cannot find reject'

Comment: yep it was just a sample of idea, not tested. you should remove reject from it